# Put JSON data onto a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm successfully printing the JSON data, but, how do I put that same data onto a UITextView, for example?

```
  @IBOutlet weak var dataView: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "apple.com")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (response, data, error) in

        if let data = data {
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The string I'm pulling isn't the actual data It's just an example.

Comment: What problem are you having? Just set `StockData.text = yourString`. Do it within a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block. Also, you shouldn't Capitalize variable names.

Comment: Do not use `NSURLConnection`. Use `URLConnection in Swift.

Comment: @Don It crashes when I do that.

Comment: Please edit your question with your new code.

Comment: Oh, if you changed your variable name from `StockData` to `dataView`, it's no longer a valid `IBOutlet`. You'll need to reconnect it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Don mentioned, you need to update the UI object on the main thread.  Like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.dataView.text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
}
```

Comment: I see the confusion now, I'm trying to get 'json' to be read as a string.